# Can I still use WMI Com API for C++ to get get CPU usage , Even though WMI is being deprecated?

Tags: c++, windows, wmi, winrm, cim

I heard that WMI is being deprecated . Some say get-WMIObject is deprecated. What should I use to get System statistics like CPU usage , RAM etc USING C++.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winrm/winrm-c---api    "OR" 
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/com-api-for-wmi

I will be getting statistics of local computer. I am confused what to use WMI or WINRM or GET-CIMINSTANCE for c++.

Any other way to get those statistics using C++ (for both Windows/Linux) is also appreciated.

Comment: Here is a good read that underlines WMI, CIM and OMI. https://www.petri.com/what-is-the-difference-between-wmi-and-cim

Comment: I read that already. I want to get system info using C++. The link says use Get CIMinstance and not Get WMI object.  But I belive only WMI com API is exposed. How can I use GET-CIMinstance in C++. Or shall I continue using COM WMI API even though the link you mentioned says GET WMI OBJECT is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for CPU usage, there's [GetSystemTimes()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getsystemtimes?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

In general, consider using [performance counter API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/perfctrs/consuming-counter-data).